# Android: Launching Activity with spefic Activity alone

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am having two apps (App A & B),with IPC between them (through AIDL). I am having three activities in App A (say Act 1 ,2 & 3). Currently i opened the App A and i moved to Act 3 from Act 1 & 2 (Act 1 -> 2 -> 3) and i am going background by pressing the device home button. Now i am launching App B which will launch the App A 's 1st activity (i.e, Act 1).

I could launch the Act 1 of App A (I am launching with Intent flag **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**), but when i finish that activity i am seeing Act 3 of App A, not the App B.

I want the App B to be there when i finish the Act 1 of App A. I tried the combination of **Clear_Task + New_Task** intent flag but it didnt workout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little surf in the developer site I could find the solution as follows

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true" 
android:taskAffinity="YOUR STRING"
```

I added the above tags for the activity in manifest. With the combination of **android:taskAffinity="YOUR STRING" and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** we can launch the activity in the separate Task so that the on finishing it will go to the caller activity.

Answer (score 0):

Have you written the code in onBackPressed() of Activity 1 of App A
If yes then 
just write that code on condition basis
means just send some flags using intent and check those flags.